# Doesn't the Many Worlds interpretation of Quantum Mechanics rail to remove randomness?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, randomness

In the Copenhagen Interpretation, the observed state of a particle is random. In the Many Worlds interpretation, the all possible observed state of a particle are true, an the universe "splits". But isn't the version of the universe you are in after "splitting" also random, therefore not actually solving the problem of fundamental randomness?

Comment: Yes, and randomness isn't a "problem".

Comment: But wouldn't "you" be in one of the the split realities? Eg. Why do "you" observe Schrodinger's cat dead while the other "you" observes it alive? Isn't it essentially random because the "you" who saw the cat dead could have seen it alive had he been the other "you". The chances of you before the observation becoming the "you" who sees it dead is essentially random. Basically, whether you actually experience A or B is random

Comment: Please keep in mind that randomness in quantum mechanics is weighted, the probabilities are weighted by the quantum mechanical equations. The death of the cat is weighted by the basic quantum mechanical  decay probability.

Comment: imo the many worlds interpretation is an example of the difference in basic thinking about reality , it is the ultimate platonic axiom "mathematics creates reality" . The other view is " reality is *modeled* by mathematics".

Comment: @user250486 Yes. That's why I wrote "yes". What I'm saying is that randomness was never a problem to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

The randomness goes away because the observer splits along with the world.  Most of the difficulty people have with Many Worlds comes from thinking that there is just one observer, but in fact an observer is a quantum mechanical object like everything else.

Comment: This is just some metaphysical comment that has nothing to do with physics. As far as physics is concerned, the individual observer's observations are random.

Comment: My guess is that you and I are using the same words to mean different things.  Surely you won't argue that in MW there is only one observer.

Comment: QM can have one observer or multiple observers, without changing the physics. This doesn't change when you add a metaphysical interpretation to it.

Comment: Ok, then, what is the metaphysical component of my answer?

Comment: Substitute "measurement instrument" for "observer", and the metaphysical content is gone.  Is it , in your opinion, a metaphysical idea that an observer and a measurement instrument are equivalent?

Comment: Quantum interpretations themselves are metaphysics. My point is that QM can accomodate any number of observers regardless of your "interpretation".

Comment: But back to your answer: the question asks if the observations of an individual observer are probabilistic. You say "No, because the observer himself splits into multiple observers". This is a metaphysical spin on what counts as an observer, which does not change the fundamental fact that all your observations remain probabilistic, i.e. you cannot determine what exactly you will see on your apparatus.

Comment: Here is where I think *you* may be inadvertently putting a metaphysical spin on your interpretation: * What do you mean by "you"?*  Your last statement suggests continuity of "you" along a single branch.  But in MW, there is continuity along both branches.  Ask, "If you are one branch of a branching rope, what is the probability you will find yourself to be *the branch you are*?"   A correct answer is "100%"!   The question and answer are quite different if "you" are not part of the system.